# Unable to read file from main.m in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a command line application that I am building in Objective-C, and inside the main.m file, I am trying to read in a document as follows:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        // Create the managed object context
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = managedObjectContext();
        NSString *pathToMyFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFileRTF" ofType:@"rtf"];
        // Custom code here...
        //at this point, pathToMyFile is nil, which means nothing happens

        // Save the managed object context
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error while saving %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When my code steps past the line:

```
NSString *pathToMyFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFileRTF" ofType:@"rtf"];
```

"pathToMyFile" is nil, and therefore nothing happens. Am I supposed to use different syntax for reading files in a command line application vs an iOS application?

Comment: Try printing the `[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]` and then verify that `MyFileRTF.rtf` actually exists in that directory.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.  When I use the line: NSLog(@"The file location is: %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFileRTF" ofType:@"rtf"]);  My output is: The file location is: (null)

Comment: When you try the line `NSLog(@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]);`, what is the output?

Comment: /Users/MyName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ReadFileTest-aulyqaeqivlhiebkxfqidpmdynvg/Build/Products/Debug

Comment: I have the file in the project directory, but because this is a command line application, I can't find the target directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you develop a command line application, Xcode does not create an app bundle (the way it does with an iOS application). Instead it just creates a Unix executable file that it places somewhere deep in the file system under the user's Library directory. Consequently, resource files included in the project are not automatically copied to the directory that `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource]` searches.

To copy a resource file to the resource path

- open the project settings
- select Build Phases
- click on the plus sign at the upper left, with tooltip "Add a new
  build phase"
- select "New Copy Files Build Phase"
- click on the plus sign at the bottom, with tooltip "Add items"
- select the text file and click "Add"

In the screen shot below, green circles are things to click on, blue rectangles are things to note.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, but how would I get a reference to the file from inside the application?

Comment: As long as the file is in the same directory as the executable, the `pathForResource` method should find it.  This means, of course, that if you move the executable to some other location, you'll have to move the text file with it.